# AngularJS doesn't update selected option

Tags: angularjs-scope, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have the following problem.
In my controller I have this variables:

```
$scope.types = [
    {id: 0, name: $translate.instant("FIRST")},
    {id: 1, name: $translate.instant("SECOND")},
    {id: 2, name: $translate.instant("THIRD")},
    {id: 3, name: $translate.instant("FOURTH")}
];
$scope.itemtype = {};
$scope.itemtype = $scope.types[0];
```

In my view I have this select

```
            <select class="form-control" 
                    required
                    ng-model="itemtype"
                    ng-options="item as item.name for item in types track by item.id">
            </select>
```

I have similar selects that work perfectly, but this isn't working, if I select the second option in the model the old value remains selected, but in the explorer I'm viewing the second option as the selected.

In firebug I'm viewing this output

```
        <select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" ng-options="item as item.name for item in types track by item.id" ng-model="itemtype" required="" tabindex="0" aria-required="false" aria-invalid="false">
        <option value="0" label="First">First</option>
        <option value="1" label="Second">Second</option>
        <option value="2" label="Third"> Third </option>
        <option value="3" selected="selected" label="Fourth"> Fourth </option>
        </select>
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used 'select as' and 'track by' together, but API document say:

> Do not use select as and track by in the same expression. They are not designed to work together.

Reference:

https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/docs/api/ng/directive/select

http://gurustop.net/blog/2014/01/28/common-problems-and-solutions-when-using-select-elements-with-angular-js-ng-options-initial-selection/